# Server overload upon deleting files

Tags: web-hosting, cache, webserver

On my website, I've shared a few files that could be downloaded and installed by XBMC / Kodi software, i.e addons and a repository to download and install these addons.

Now, here's the interesting part, when I delete a certain folder which contains 2 files "addons.xml" "addons.xml.md5" - the server is getting overloaded straight away. even though the folder and its files were never essential part of of the addon itself, that is, users never needed to access that folder or to do anything with the files in it (it was there for testing porpuses).

Now, if I replace the original files with empty ones (same file-names but no content) the site runs fine, yet when I delete them - the entire server may crash.

it has been like that for over 6 months with that folder.

Recently I've uploaded a zip file (that could also be used by Kodi) only for a few days, after deleting that file - the same thing happened.

Now I'm stuck, having dummy files scattered all-over my website, what can I do? / how can I prevent Kodi from requesting these files?

Comment: Does Kodi have a support forum?? It sounds like a code issue or a usage issue.

Comment: I wonder if this "Kodi" is a script bot that consistently attempts to access files. Have you manually tried accessing a non-existing file in the folder via a web browser? It might be that your error 404 handler is setup to run some malicious script that causes overload?

Comment: @Mike I have and it goes straight to a 404 page I've written myself. have just  took a glimpse at it and the code there hasn't changed (I don't think I was hacked). Any other idea?

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? How / when / from where are these files being accessed?

Comment: Basically it gives a client ip address then SoftException in Application.cpp:574: Could not execute script <SOME PHP FILE> (can be anything) or Caused by SystemException in API_Linux.cpp:444: execve() for program "/ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54" failed: Resource temporarily unavailable or Premature end of script headers: <SOME PHP FILE> (can be anything)

Those 3 errors are usually showing up together one after another...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about webmastering as per http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic